# Removed answer by a moderator???

Tags: feature-request, moderation, serverfault

I think mrdenny deleted one of my answers and I think it's because I've just linked external material w/o providing a solution.

Nothing to say about the reason, but I think it'd be better to let the user know what is happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just looked through all the answers deleted in the last two weeks, the only two of yours that were "deleted" were questions migrated to superuser. Perhaps you could provide a link so we can take a look?

Comment: Apologizes, it's just my fault, I have answered to an other question (mixed up with questions). I'll pay more attention from now on. Apologizes.